# Spring Security with REST web services - cannot authenticate via header when testing with Curl

Tags: web-services, spring, api, spring-security, restful-authentication

I'm new to Spring and spring security and I can't seem to get this working.   I'm securing a web service with Spring security.   I'm getting the appropriate responses back - 401, 200, etc - for the secure requests and when I explicitely login to the URL I defined.   However, when I try to test the actual url providing data via curl or poster sending the authentication in the header, I can't get it to work.

Here's my servlet-security.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<http create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
  <intercept-url pattern="/services/schedule/**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>

  <custom-filter ref="myFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>

  <!-- Adds a logout filter to Spring Security filter chain -->
    <logout logout-url="/api/logout" delete-cookies="true" invalidate-session="true"
        success-handler-ref="restLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="myFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
  <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
  <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="mySuccessHandler"/>
  <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/api/login"/>
    <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="username"/>
    <beans:property name="passwordParameter" value="password"/>
    <beans:property name="postOnly" value="true"/>
 </beans:bean>

 <!-- Configures a custom authentication success handler that returns HTTP status code 200 -->
 <beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="com.touchvision.pilot.security.RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

 <!-- Configures a custom authentication failure handler that returns HTTP status code 401 -->
 <beans:bean id="restAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="com.touchvision.pilot.security.RestAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

  <!-- Configures a custom logout success handler that returns HTTP status code 200 -->
  <beans:bean id="restLogoutSuccessHandler" class="com.touchvision.pilot.security.RestLogoutSuccessHandler"/>

<!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
                <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the database -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

    <!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.touchvision.pilot.services.CustomUserDetailsService"/>

</beans:beans>
```

As I said, I can login fine via posting the creds to the /api/login.  However, when I try to send the authentication in the header with an actual data request, I get an error that says "This request requires HTTP authentication."   The curl command I'm using is:

```
curl -u admin@touchvision.com:admin123 "http://local.touchvision.com/services/schedule/list"
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have a form-login filter (`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`) configured that processes form parameters passed in a HTTP POST request, but there is nothing on the server side that would process the *header* of a request.

Try configuring a `BasicAuthenticationFilter` that will authenticate requests based on info passed in the header.

Comment: Ah-ha.   Do I need to add <http-basic /> to the http block for this to work?

Comment: Yep, see details at http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/ns-config.html#ns-form-and-basic

Comment: UGH!!!!  That worked.  Thank you!  I've actually read a lot of the documentation.   It's just been a bit overwhelming and confusing at times.  Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using %40 intead of the @ sign in the user ID.  Also, depending on your version of CURL, you may want to try quotes around the entire -u parameter.